# concatenate strings with memmove() in function

Tags: c, string, string-concatenation, memmove

I want to concatenate two strings using a function that returns the resulting string.  it would be something like this:

```
char *String_Concat (char *String_1, char *String_2)
{
    char *StringResult;

    //memmove String_1 to StringResult
    //memmove String_2 to StringResult

    return StringResult;
}
```

I wonder if that is a good way of doing that, since I know little about memory management.  StringResult does not have a defined length, and I am not sure what will happen after two memmove operations.

I suppose StringResult will be cleaned up by the function itself, since I do not use malloc(), correct?

Comment: But you *must* use `malloc`! Where else can you copy the strings to?

Comment: `memmove` is not for that, it's for overlapping memory blocks, for that you should use `memcpy`.

Comment: but memcpy() does not handle overlapping well.  there is that null character.

Comment: @CaTx that has nothing to do with overlapping.

Comment: You'll need to have a buffer large enough to hold the result, either using malloc or passing in one that is large enough are your best options. Take a look at the strcat function for an example. You could strcpy the first string into a big enough buffer and then strcat the second string to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char *String_Concat (char *String_1, char *String_2)
{
    size_t len1 = strlen(String_1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(String_2);
    char *StringResult = malloc(len1+len2+1);
    //might want to check for malloc-error...
    memcpy(StringResult, String_1, len1);
    memcpy(&StringResult[len1], String_2, len2+1);
    return StringResult;
}
```

So, C has the concept of `storage` for objects. The storage of an object determines its lifetime, as C is not garbage-collected. If you want to create a new string, You must reserve storage for it. The easiest way would be **automatic** storage, but that is associated with the **scope** of the function it is declared in, so automatic variables cease to exist after function return. Alternatively, you could use **static** storage, but that cannot be of variable size, and multiple calls to the function would use the same storage. Finally, you can use **allocated** storage, which requires `malloc()/calloc()/realloc()/free()`.
See C11 draft standard, section `6.2.4 Storage durations of objects`

Comment: I tried doing that.  the problem is malloc() required a free() with it.  but free() defeats 'return StringResult'.  see my problem?

Comment: @CaTx `free` doesn't defeat anything you should free it after returning.

Comment: The function that uses the returned string is responsible for freeing it when it is done with it. A less confusing solution is to malloc it outside of the sting_concat function, and pass in the malloc'ed pointer as a parameter - then you don't have a malloc hiding in the function and it is easier to make sure your mallocs and frees are paired up.

Comment: @alk by the way i had a conversation with this OP, he doesn't want to have to `free` manually, apparently he wants to translate his code from C# almost literally. He wants to have some oneliners. I upvoted this answer and it was my first answer, although EOF posted it before me by a few seconds, but it's not what the OP wants.

Comment: @iharob: "*he doesn't want to have to free manually*" then the OP better stays with C# ...

Comment: @alk I told the OP to use c++ instead, but the OP wants c.

Comment: @iharob: Then point the OP to C tutorials and documentation. The standard is pretty useful...

Comment: thx everyone for the help.  a 2-liner seems to be the best compromise now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would handle it, using existing string commands instead of memcpy. I'm assuming you want something like strcat that doesn't affect the source strings.

```
char* string_concat(char *dest, const char* string1, const char* string2)
{
   strcpy(dest, string1);
   strcat(dest, string2);
   return dest;
}
```

To use it, you need to pass in a pointer to the buffer you want the result stored in. You can use malloc to make it the size you need. Free it when you're done.

```
char *str1 = "abc";
char *str2 = "def";
size_t len = strlen(str1) + strlen(str2);
char *newstr = malloc(len + 1);
string_concat(newstr, str1, str2);
printf("%s\n", newstr);
free(newstr);
```

There is simply no way to deal with arbitrary-length strings without allocating memory, so you'll be stuck with malloc/free unless you're using character arrays with fixed lengths. If you want to abstract the logic of deciding how big of a buffer to allocate you can do something like this:

```
size_t string_concat(char* dest, char* string1, char* string2)
{
   if(!dest)
   {
      return strlen(string1) + strlen(string2) + 1;
   }
   strcpy(dest, string1);
   strcat(dest, string2);
   return 0;
}
```

Then you can ask it how much to allocate like this:

```
char* newstr = malloc(string_concat(0, str1, str2));
```

But you lose the syntactical convenience of it returning a pointer to dest.

Comment: 1+ for proposing the "dry-run" option! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's a very bad idea, and no "cleaning" will magically happen by the function.

You cannot do this, it's not a valid way to implement string concatenation in C.

You *must* make sure there's enough writable memory before doing anything, so in general you must call `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid dynamic allocation you can do something like

```
int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
    char        String_1[8] = "Exa";
    /*                   ^ enough space for Example\0 */
    const char *String_2    = "mple";

    printf("%s\n", strcat(String_1, String_2));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, assuming using `memmove()` was just an idea, not a requirement, [strcpy()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncpy.3.html) and [strcat()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html) are functions of choice here, as they are specially crafted to work on C-"strings", that is `0`-terminated `char`-arrays.

```
#include  <stdlib.h> /* for malloc() */
#include  <string.h> /* for strcpy() and strcat() */
#include  <errno.h> /* for errno and EINVAL */

char * stralloc_and_cat(const char * s1, const char * s2)
{ 
  char * s = NULL;

  if ((NULL == s1) || (NULL == s2))
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
  }
  else 
  {
    if (NULL != (s = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1)))
    {
      strcpy(s, s1);
      strcat(s, s2);
    }
  }

  return s;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <stdio.h>

char * stralloc_and_cat(const char * s1, const char * s2);

int main(void)
{
  char * s1 = "hello ";
  char * s2 = "world";

  char s = stralloc_and_cat(s1, s2);
  if (NULL == s)
  {
    perror("stralloc_and_cat() failed");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("%s\n", s);

    free(s);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `malloc()` to dynamically allocate some memory for the resulting concat string.
And in this case the caller is responsible to invoke `free()` to release the memory pointed by the returned string pointer.

An alternative would be to design a function expecting a pointer to a caller-allocated destination buffer, large enough to store the total resulting string.

Following the first option, you can consider code like this ([**live on Ideone**](http://ideone.com/TCNMQN)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Concatenates string1 and string2.
// Returns the concatenated (string1+string2), or NULL on errors.
// NOTE: Memory for the returned string is allocated with malloc() 
// by the function, so the caller is responsible to release it with
// a call to free().
char *StringConcat(const char *string1, const char *string2)
{
    char *stringResult;
    size_t len1;
    size_t len2;

    // Check for NULL pointers...
    // (Return NULL, or whatever your design is...)
    if (string1 == NULL || string2 == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    len1 = strlen(string1);
    len2 = strlen(string2);

    // +1 for terminating NUL ('\0')
    stringResult = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1);
    if (stringResult == NULL) {
        return NULL; // Allocation error
    }

    // Copy characters from first string    
    // (exclduing the terminating NUL --> len1)
    memcpy(stringResult, string1, len1);

    // Copy characters from second string
    // (including the terminating NUL --> len2+1)
    memcpy(stringResult + len1, string2, len2+1);

    // Return destination string pointer to the caller.
    // NOTE: Memory must be freed by the caller calling free().
    return stringResult;
}


// *** TEST ***
int main(void)
{
    // Test the function
    char * str = StringConcat("Hello ", "World");

    // Print the resulting string
    printf("%s\n", str);

    // Don't forget to free() memory allocatd by the concat function
    free(str);

    // All right
    return 0;
}
```